# circular IO redirection

Tags: linux, io

I have a process I start on my shell that prints out data and I have a python script that calculates it and should return that to the process. How can I do that?

I know using `pipe` or `>` could help me with one side, but how can I achieve a two-way redirection?

Is something like: `my_process | my_script | my_process` legal?

*What I want to happen:*

1. start process from shell
2. process sends data to my script (instead of printing it to STDOUT)
3. my script returns an answer to process (instead of printing it to
   STDOUT)
4. return to step 2

Comment: Maybe you can use bash coprocess to do this? I've never tried it, but it seems to do what you want. See http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/keywords/coproc for examples

Answer (score 1):

It's emulatable with FIFOs (or if you're using python, you can create your own pipes with the pipe system call and redirect them according to your arrangement).

Some example code:

```
#!/bin/sh
#note: the resource management and error handling here is not very clean or robust
mkfifo fifo0 fifo1
exec 3<>fifo0
exec 4<>fifo1
rm -f fifo0 fifo1
many()
{
    i=0
    while [ $i -lt $1 ]; do
        echo -n x
        i=$((i+1))
    done
    echo
}
proc1()
{
    ulimit_p=$(ulimit -p)
    while :; do
        echo proc1_msg
        echo >&2 proc1_written=proc1_msg
        read var
        echo >&2 proc1_read=$var
        sleep 1
    done
}

proc2()
{
    while :; do
        read var
        echo >&2 proc2_read=$var
        echo proc2_msg
        echo >&2 proc2_written=proc2_msg
    done
}
pid=0
trap 'echo kill $pid; kill $pid; exit 130' INT
proc1 <&3 >&4 & pid=$!
proc2 <&4 >&3
```

Comment: Thx for you answer, but I'm mega noob in linux. Could you pls dumb it down a bit? :)